# MongoDB - Assign value from $where

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to, as stated in the title, assign a value inside the $project scope, using the $where command, and thus returning a string as a value?

It would look something like this:

[image: MongoDB Shell $project]

And if it's not possible, what is a different way to get the matched regex as I would using the JavaScript function above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use

{ : { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '' } }

{ : { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '' } }

{ : { $regex: /pattern/ } }